# REGEX : How to escape []?

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on strings like `"[ro.multiboot]: [1]"`. How do I just select 1(it can also be 0) out of this string?

I am looking for a regex in Java.

Comment: Which language are you looking for a regex for? Different languages and tools implement different regex syntaxes.

Comment: Also, are the quotes part of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@paxdiablo's regexps are correct, but complete answer for "How do I just select 1(it can also be 0) out of this string?" is:

### 1. very simple solution

```java
    String input = "[ro.multiboot]: [1]";
    String matched = input.replaceFirst( "^.*\\[ro.multiboot\\].*\\[([01])\\].*$", "$1" );
```

### 2. same functionality, more complicated but with better performance

```java
    String input = "[ro.multiboot]: [1]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "^.*\\[ro.multiboot\\].*\\[([01])\\].*$" );
    Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
    String matched = null;
    if ( m.matches() ) matched = m.group( 1 );
```

Performance is better because the pattern is compiled just once (for example when you are matching array os such `String`s);

**Notes:**

- in both examples the group is part of regexps between `(` and `)` (if not escaped)
- in Java you have to use `\\[`, because `\[` returns error - it is not correct escape sequence for `String`

Answer (score 4):

Usually, you would do something like (assuming 0 and 1 were the only options):

```
^.*\[([01])\].*$
```

If you only wanted the value for `ro.multiboot`, you could change it to something like:

```
^.*\[ro.multiboot\].*\[([01])\].*$
```

(depending on how complex any of the non-bracketed stuff is allowed to be).

These would both basically only extract the value between square brackets if it were zero or one, and capture it into a capture variable so you could use it.

Of course, regex is not a world-wide standard, nor are the environments in which you use it. That means it depends a lot on your actual environment how you will actually code this up.

---

For Java, the following sample program may help:

import java.util.regex.*;

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*\\[ro.multiboot\\].*\\[([01])\\].*$");
        String str;
        Matcher m;

        str = "[ro.multiboot]: [0]";
        m = p.matcher (str);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println ("str0 has " + m.group(1));
        }

        str = "[ro.multiboot]: [1]";
        m = p.matcher (str);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println ("str1 has " + m.group(1));
        }

        str = "[ro.multiboot]: [2]";
        m = p.matcher (str);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println ("str2 has " + m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

This results in (as expected):

```
str0 has 0
str1 has 1
```